# How to generate OpenAPI via Gradle for Amazon Selling Partner API models?

Tags: gradle, openapi, openapi-generator

I'm new to Gradle (using 7.3.2) and currently trying to integrate org.openapi.generator's openApiGenerate task for all json OpenAPI template files of Amazon's selling partner API models from https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-models.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.ajoberstar.grgit' version '4.1.1'
    id 'org.openapi.generator' version '5.3.0'
}

import org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit

project.ext.repoDirectory = "$buildDir/selling-partner-api-models"
project.ext.basePackage = "com.amazon.sellingpartner"

tasks.register('deleteRepo', Delete) {
    delete project.ext.repoDirectory
}

class CloneSpapi extends DefaultTask {
    @Input
    String url = 'https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-models.git'

    @TaskAction
    def clone() {
        println 'Cloning Amazon Selling Partner OpenAPI from github ...'
        def grgit = Grgit.clone(dir: project.ext.repoDirectory, uri: url)
        grgit.close()
        println 'done'
    }
}

tasks.register('cloneSpapi', CloneSpapi) {
    description 'Clones Amazon Selling Partner OpenAPI from github'
    dependsOn tasks.named('deleteRepo')
}

interface GenerateParameters extends WorkParameters {
    RegularFileProperty getJsonFile()
    DirectoryProperty getOutputDir()
}

abstract class GenerateApi implements WorkAction<GenerateParameters> {
    @Override
    void execute() {
        def file = parameters.jsonFile.get().getAsFile()
        def modelName = file.getName().replace('.json', '')
        println modelName + ": " + file
    }
}

abstract class GenerateApis extends DefaultTask {
    private final WorkerExecutor workerExecutor

    @Input
    abstract String directory = "$project.ext.repoDirectory/models"

    @Inject
    GenerateApis(WorkerExecutor workerExecutor) {
        this.workerExecutor = workerExecutor
    }

    @TaskAction
    void generateFiles() {
        ConfigurableFileTree tree = project.fileTree(dir: directory)
        tree.include '**/*.json'
    
        Set<File> modelFiles = tree.getFiles().sort()
        
        WorkQueue workQueue = workerExecutor.noIsolation()

        modelFiles.each { File file ->
            workQueue.submit(GenerateApi.class) { GenerateParameters parameters ->
                parameters.jsonFile = file
            }
        }
    }
}

tasks.register('generateApis', GenerateApis) {
}

openApiGenerate { 
    generatorName = "java"
    inputSpec = // file
    outputDir = "$buildDir/generated".toString()
    invokerPackage = "$project.ext.basePackage"
    apiPackage = "$project.ext.basePackage" + ".api.modelName" // modelName from 
    modelPackage = "$project.ext.basePackage" + ".model.modelName" // modelName here
    configOptions = [
        dateLibrary: "java8"
    ]
}
```

To simplify things, I have added a simple 'cloneSpapi' task to clone the repository.

```
gradle -q cloneSpapi
```

How do I call the openApiGenerate task for each template file?

Answer (score 0):

I have now used the swagger.io library directly and was able to call the code generator directly.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("io.swagger:swagger-codegen:2.4.24")
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.ajoberstar.grgit' version '4.1.1'
}

import io.swagger.codegen.DefaultGenerator
import io.swagger.codegen.config.CodegenConfigurator

import org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit

project.ext.repoDirectory = "$buildDir/selling-partner-api-models"
project.ext.basePackage = "com.amazon.sellingpartner"
project.ext.outputDir = new File(project.buildDir, '/generated')

tasks.register('deleteRepo', Delete) {
    delete project.ext.repoDirectory
}

class CloneSpapi extends DefaultTask {
    @Input
    String url = 'https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-models.git'

    @TaskAction
    def clone() {
        println 'Cloning Amazon Selling Partner OpenAPI from github ...'
        def grgit = Grgit.clone(dir: project.ext.repoDirectory, uri: url)
        grgit.close()
        println 'done'
    }
}

tasks.register('cloneSpapi', CloneSpapi) {
    description 'Clones Amazon Selling Partner OpenAPI from github'
    dependsOn tasks.named('deleteRepo')
}

interface GenerateParameters extends WorkParameters {
    RegularFileProperty getJsonFile()
    DirectoryProperty getTemplateDir()
    DirectoryProperty getOutputDir()
    Property<String> getBasePackage()
}

abstract class GenerateApi implements WorkAction<GenerateParameters> {
    @Override
    void execute() {
        def file = parameters.jsonFile.get().getAsFile()
        def modelName = file.getName().replace('.json', '')
        println "Generating OpenAPI for $modelName"
        
        def basePackage = parameters.basePackage.get()

        def config = new CodegenConfigurator()
        config.setInputSpec(file.toString()) // The swagger API file
        config.setLang("java")
        config.setTemplateDir(parameters.templateDir.get().toString())
        config.setOutputDir(parameters.outputDir.get().toString())   // The output directory, user-service-contract/build/user-service-server/
        config.setInvokerPackage(basePackage)
        config.setApiPackage(basePackage + ".api." + modelName)            // Package to be used for the API interfaces
        config.setModelPackage(basePackage + ".model." + modelName)        // Package to be used for the API models
        config.setAdditionalProperties([
                'dateLibrary'     : 'java8', // Date library to use
                'useTags'         : 'true'   // Use tags for the naming
        ])
        
        def generator = new DefaultGenerator();
        generator.opts(config.toClientOptInput());
        generator.generate()
    }
}

abstract class GenerateApis extends DefaultTask {
    private final WorkerExecutor workerExecutor

    @Input
    abstract String directory = "$project.ext.repoDirectory/models"

    @Inject
    GenerateApis(WorkerExecutor workerExecutor) {
        this.workerExecutor = workerExecutor
    }

    @TaskAction
    void generate() {
        ConfigurableFileTree tree = project.fileTree(dir: directory)
        tree.include '**/*.json'
    
        Set<File> modelFiles = tree.getFiles().sort()
        
        WorkQueue workQueue = workerExecutor.noIsolation()

        modelFiles.each { File file ->
            workQueue.submit(GenerateApi.class) { GenerateParameters parameters ->
                parameters.jsonFile = file
                parameters.templateDir = new File(project.ext.repoDirectory, 'clients/sellingpartner-api-aa-java/resources/swagger-codegen/templates')
                parameters.outputDir = project.ext.outputDir
                parameters.basePackage = project.ext.basePackage
            }
        }
    }
}

tasks.register('deleteGenerated', Delete) {
    delete project.ext.outputDir
}

tasks.register('generateApis', GenerateApis) {
    dependsOn tasks.named('deleteGenerated'), tasks.named('cloneSpapi')
}
```

Comment: does this create files for all the api models in same client?